# iPhone memory management, EXC_BAD_ACCESS NSString between views

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsstring, view

I have some problems with memory management, I think my problem is the assignment, and object releases. I want to assign a NSString (userID) value to another NSString in other view (user_id).

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import "OnlineCheckViewController.h"

@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *userID;
}
@end
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

- (IBAction)OnlineCheck:(id)sender
{
    OnlineCheckViewController *controller = [[OnlineCheckViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OnlineCheckViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.user_id = userID;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    userID = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [userID release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

**OnlineCheckViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "OnlineCheckResultsViewController.h"

@protocol OnlineCheckViewControllerDelegate;

@interface OnlineCheckViewController : UIViewController 
     <OnlineCheckResultsViewControllerDelegate>
{
    NSString *user_id;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <OnlineCheckViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *user_id;

@end
```

**OnlineCheckViewController.m**

```
#import "OnlineCheckViewController.h"

@synthesize user_id;
@synthesize delegate=_delegate;

- (void)dealloc
{
    [user_id release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setUser_id:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see where user_id or userID are being created (alloc'd). With an assignment like user_id = userID you would not be performing a [... release] on both. You would need to release only one of them. Also, do not assign nil before releasing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all your answers.

I have resolved this issue.

In **MainViewController.h**

I have added userID IBOutlet

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet NSString *userID;
```

In **MainViewController.m**

```
@synthesize userID;

- (IBAction)OnlineCheck:(id)sender
{
controller.user_id = self.userID;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
self.userID = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
[userID release];
}
```

In **OnlineCheckViewController.h**

Changed to assign

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *user_id;
```

In **OnlineCheckViewController.m**

```
- (void)dealloc
{
// removed
// [user_id release];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
// removed
// [self setUser_id:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSString *userID;
}
```

I'm going to bet that this is your problem. Note that when you create the property "user_id", you specify "retain". Retain makes sure that the processor doesn't release the string until you tell it to.

An NSString is automatically set to auto release. If you plan to keep the value in the non property NSString (userID) then you need to call [userID retain]; after you set the value of it.

I'm guessing that you never retained userID and when you try to set user_id to it, it calls the error **or** more likely, it throws the error because you release it in dealloc.

Comment: I have added userID IBOutlet property in MainViewController.h and that works!

Comment: That shouldn't have fixed it... Unless adding it as an interface builder property retains it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (IBAction)OnlineCheck:(id)sender
{
    OnlineCheckViewController *controller = [[OnlineCheckViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"OnlineCheckViewController" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.user_id = userID;
    [controller.user_id retain];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

i think this may solve your problem...

Comment: I have changed the property user_id to assign in OnlineCheckViewController.h and that works!

Comment: That's great but you can assign when variable is int, float... but not when it is String or array...